# Login to GNOME (Fedora) using my FreeIPA credentials

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, kerberos

I have a FreeIPA Server (Fedora Server 23) and a FreeIPA Client (Fedora Server 23 with GNOME). Everything works excepts one thing: I can't login to Fedora Client with my FreeIPA username and password. The system successfully checked my credentials, but after that the system is logged me off. If I "mistype" the password, it respond with error, so the (Kerberos) authentication works.

What's wrong with my client (or my server) configuration?

P.S.: Here's some print screen about my GNOME's users settings:
The FreeIPA user:

[image]

The FreeIPA users's history:

[image]